# Trying to read file_url of .csv file in Padas returning file not found

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, file

This was exercise during my class that I was not able to attend so I am catching up privately.
I am trying to read my .csv file using Pandas. I am using Jupiter, and mentioned .csv file in upload in my Jupiter correctly.
But for some reason my code isn't able to read my file.

Could you have an idea why please?
Thanks!
** Sample data: HR Employee Attrition and Performance ** You can get it from here:
I have downloaded this file from following url, and uploaded it in my Jupiter.
https://www.kaggle.com/patelprashant/employee-attrition#WA_Fn-UseC_-HR-Employee-Attrition.csv

`file_url = "HR_Employee_Attrition.csv"`

`data = pd.read_csv(file_url)`

### ​
`data.head()` ##-> same as data.head(5)

````
<ipython-input-19-201da5b1caca> in <module>
----> 1 data = pd.read_csv(file_url)
      2 # here the rows are being indexed by one of the columns ->  'EmployeeNumber'
      3 # all other column headings of the csv file would become columns.
      4 
      5 data.head()  ## same as data.head(5)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    446 
    447     # Create the parser.
--> 448     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    449 
    450     if chunksize or iterator:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    878             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    879 
--> 880         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    881 
    882     def close(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1112     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1113         if engine == "c":
-> 1114             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1115         else:
   1116             if engine == "python":

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1889         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1890 
-> 1891         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1892         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1893 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File HR_Employee_Attrition.csv does not exist: 'HR_Employee_Attrition.csv'```
````

Comment: Have you uploaded the CSV file in the same folder as your notebook? If no, specify the complete path to the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the location of csv in pd.read function csv parameter is not correct one. so check the path of the csv file (provide full path location string in the parameter).